# empty window with title "download elementary os" pops up after every log-in

Tags: release-freya

I installed elementary OS earlier this week and since than after every log-in (even log-in after wake-up from hibernate) one or two big empty windows with the titel "download elementary os" pop up and disapear after a while. It is kind of annoying, and well obviously I already downloaded elementary OS, otherwise I could not run it on my computer. I am running freya 0.3.1

Does anybody know how to disable this empty windows poping up?

Thanks for any advice
Olaf

Comment: @Raven thanks it seems the chmod trick did the job. Although I do not understand why giving the captive_portal_test executable rights (chmod -x) stops it from poping up - or is it, that the window pops up when the captive test is stucked in the middle because of lacking execution rights to proceed?